# how to achieve same compression in linux and windows

Tags: linux, windows, jar, zip, unzip

I have a example.jar file.
  I'm trying update a class file in the jar.
  when I'm packing the class file using jar or zip utility(**command line-linux**)

> I tried :
>
> jar uf my MyJarFile.jar MyclassFile.class
>
> zip -u my MyJarFile.jar MyclassFile.class

I get some checksum assume XXYYZZ.

But when I pack the same class file in windows using **7zip(GUI)** I get different checksum say MMNNOO.
  This is because of change in compression ratio.I mean size also differs.

Now my question is how can I achieve same compression ratio **ie same checksum**.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is due to slight difference in how files are sorted, prioritised and similar in the two different implementations.

Even if the compression algorithms are exactly the same OS and tool differences will create different outputs.

Forcing the same output would be challenging, but not impossible. Maybe try the compression functions in Java while forcing the exact same file encoding?